# Gmail telling what I am using to send email

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

When I send an email using phpmailer to gmail, and I look the email source, I see the following next to the "from" field:

"Using PHPMailer 6.1.7 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)"

For security reasons I'd prefer to remove that if it's possible, but I don't know if this is Gmail being smart or phpmailer appending it to every email message I send.

How can I remove it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This appears in the `X-Mailer` header. As per [the docs](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#property_XMailer), you can remove this header altogether by setting it to a space, like this:

```
$mail->XMailer = ' ';
```

If it's appearing somewhere else, I'll need to see the rest of your code and the headers of a message you've received in gmail.